# Get all records between to alpha variables in alpha order mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database of words for dictionary lookup purposes. What I need to be able to do with mysql is allow a user to input to variables (alpha) and my script will return every word that starts with both of those variables and everything in between.

Let's say the two variables are:

```php
$letters1 = abor
$letters2 = accr
```

I want to get every word that starts with `abor` through `accr`. I need to return every word that would fit between those two starting points. So an example SQL statement that I know does not work but might help you understand what I am asking:

```
SELECT word from table1 WHERE word LIKE '%abor%' THROUGH '%accr%' ORDER BY word ASC
```

I know that `THROUGH` is not an operator but that's the general idea of what I need to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you merely want words that *start* with letters between the two variables, you can use MySQL's [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator:

```
SELECT word FROM table1 WHERE word BETWEEN 'abor' AND 'accr' ORDER BY word
```

Comment: well the words can be larger than just abor. I need to be able to apply a like operator to that as well so it finds any words that have those 4 letters to start with LIKE 'abor%'

Comment: @CesarBielich: That's exactly what the above will do because, lexicographically (which is the ordering MySQL applies to text, according to the relevant collation), `aboriginal` is ordered between `abor` and `accr`.